# Cannot boot from USB, need help

Tags: boot, usb

I wanted to format my w7 drive and install Ubuntu, so I have made an Ubuntu 14. 04 bootable USB, but when I try to boot from that USB it gives this message:

**Attempting boot from USB**

Normally it should boot after this message, but it does not go any further.

I also have made a Lubuntu 14.04 bootable USB after that, which did not boot same as Ubuntu 14. 04.

There is no problem with USB disk, since the same USB disk can boot with w7 installation.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com. We're all volunteers here. How did you create the USB stick; did you consult any of the numerous available sources regarding this topic?

Comment: http://www.pchelpforum.com/threads/cannot-boot-from-usb.117914/

Comment: I tried all the tools, it did not work. I do not think rufus will make any change since all programs do the same job.
Maybe it's because im trying to install it on w7 disk ? I don't know, this computer is from 2006 as far as I can remember.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

**To create a USB installation device, you will need:**

1. a 2 GB USB flash device/drive/stick. If the iso file is smaller than 1 GB, it is possible to use a 1 GB USB device, at least with some of the methods. Files on this USB device will be erased, so backup the files you want to keep before making the device bootable. Make sure this USB device is properly formatted and mounted.
2. an Ubuntu flavour ISO file.

To get the new version of ubuntu: [click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Comment: I already did that, as I mentioned above. But it does not boot. Computer realizes there is a bootable usb but it does not boot, somehow.

Comment: And how does this help the OP?

Comment: What else do you want me to say ? I tried so many times and it failed.

Comment: did you click that link? all solutions are in that page

Comment: do you think I did not read that article ? im giving it one more try, just for you. but it won't boot again im sure.